# Adding the related username to syslog logging

Tags: debian, security, syslog, logs

I'm managing a server running Debian 7 Wheezy.
I'd like to add a new feature to the /var/log/syslog file.

That is a sample current output:

```
Jul 31 13:06:35 myserver mod_evasive[7629]: Couldn't open logfile /var/log/apache2/evasive/dos-XX.XX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied
```

(I've changed the IP for privacy).

How can I write the name of the user that attempts to write (or in general, does an operation)?

Comment: rsyslog or syslog-ng?

Comment: The user of the process doing the logging, or the user that caused the process to log?  In your case, do you want the userid of the apache process 7629 or the user that made apache call mod_evasive ?

Comment: RuiFRibeiro rsyslog
@StephenHarris Would be nice to show both.

Comment: @StephenHarris What should i do?